# Queries on analysis and design

Tags: terminology

I am developing an e-commerce application using spring and struts. I am quite confused about the following.

1. What is meant by conceptual view of the system? When I searched in the internet, I could see the diagrams with classes. But my understanding is that conceptual view is something which is derived soon after requirement gathering.
2. What is architectural view of the system? Can I explain MVC architecture here? or should I go with something else, rather more specific to my application.

Could you please help me figure this out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conceptual view (a.k.a. the conceptual schema) is a diagram of *concepts* that are related, from which a database model can be derived. For example, you might have some students, courses and modules in a conceptual view for a student management application. The model may contain properties about each concept, but only properties that relate to the properties of the real-life concept. You could later convert this into a normalized database format, containing tables that handle any many-to-many relationships, additional fields, etc.

An archictecural view separates parts of a system out into architecture categories. The categories may be related to a layered model (e.g. presentation, logic, data) or any other model. As you mentioned, MVC is a good example here. Such models are useful to understand how a project's resources and components might be partitioned.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! So, we use ER digram to achieve this conceptual modelling, don't we? I am writing my project report and confused with the hints provided in our report template. It says analysis section can contain "conceptual view of the system, use-case diagrams, ER diagram, logical data model etc" Could you tell me the difference between them?

Comment: Use-case is a diagram that shows the actions that occur on a system, usually initiated by a user. ER diagrams show the relationships between any entities - whether they be a conceptual view or a real database model. Logical data models show the relationship between data sources and data objects within the system. There are wikipedia entries for each of them, so that would be a good place to start.